# linux terminator: how to run a bash script not close it after done

Tags: bash, terminator

I am using terminator terminal in linux

I am trying to run a bash script after starting terminator.

```
$ terminator -x sh /home/test/test.sh
```

it opens terminator runs the script and closes after its finished

i want the terminator not to close after the script is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a `hold` option like in termite or xterm in the manpage of terminator, but I found an answer here ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205217/how-to-hold-terminal-open-excepting-gnome-terminal)) for terminator:

> It has an option similar to that in Gnome Terminal, you have to create
>   a profile - e.g. called "hold" - with that option enabled.
>
> To run command and stay open:
>
> ```
> terminator -e '<command>' -p hold.
> ```

Comment: i have created a profile called hold and selected `Hold the termial open` and tried `terminator -p hold -e 'ls -al'`; not able to stay open

Comment: Strange, I installed terminator to test just like you did and it worked.

Comment: Anyway, you may find other methods in the link I provided (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205217/how-to-hold-terminal-open-excepting-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

```
terminator -x sh -c '/home/test/test.sh; read -p "Press any key... " -n1'
```

Answer (score 0):

While executing the script in `terminator`, just run the shell you want and the terminator will stay

```sh
terminator -e 'echo "This will stay" && zsh || zsh'
```

`&&` and `||` will make sure that shell will execute irrespective of the scripts success or failure